Connecting to VPN from one specific network makes hosts inside VPN network unreachable - subnet conflict
Connecting to VPN from one specific network (my home's wifi 4g hostpot) makes hosts inside VPN network unreachable by pinging ip's & hostnames.
Otherwise everything works fine when connecting from coffee shop's wifi's, friends phone hotspot etc.
Here is the ping output while being succefully connected to the vpn:
$ ping 192.168.0.217
PING 192.168.0.217 (192.168.0.217) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.124 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.124 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.124 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.217 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3055ms
pipe 3

I'v tried resetting the hotspot device, still same result.

Hi and welcome to ServerFault! Just a heads up that this site is meant for business-related IT issues, not home or personal ones (use https://superuser.com instead). You may get voted down here, but I won't because I'm not like that.

Please add the output of ip route (when in my home's wifi 4g hostpot) to your post.

@TommyPeanuts It is bussines-related issue, I'm trying to reach my employer's VPN.

It was a subnet conflict between my home's hotspot and vpn.
After changing hotspot's DHCP settings:

IP Address from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.133.1
Start IP address to from 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.133.100
End IP address to from 192.168.0.199 to 192.168.133.199
Primary dns server from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.133.1
adding secondary dns server which maches VPN internal network's dns server

Issue was resolved.
